# SSH connection refused only from a specific PC

Tags: ssh, putty, sshd, yocto-project

I'm connecting to my server via **ssh** but I encounter a really weird problem.

1. I can connect to my server with local ip (192.168.** .** )
2. **I can not connect to my server via its public ip address on my own laptop**
3. My roommate can use his laptop to connect to the server via both its local and public ip address
4. I can use my mobile phone(Android) to connect to the server via both its local and public ip address (there's an awesome app named "JuiceSSH")

It seems that **only my PC** can't get connected to the server via ssh.
Here is the error log:

```
OpenSSH_7.1p2, OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to **.**.*.*** [**.**.*.***] port 22.
debug1: connect to address **.**.*.*** port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host **.**.*.*** port 22: Connection refused
```

I have tried with different internet environment (different wifi and also used my phone as a hostpot) and all got connection refused.
And with all the environment above, my phone can connect to the server using JuiceSSH.

---

I've checked the ports on the server and they are not blocked (otherwise my phone and my roommate's PC wouldn't be able to connect)

My roommate and I are **both using Windows 10**. As my roommate's PC can connect to the server without issue, I think there might be some problems with my own PC. I've tried connecting using Putty, Smartty and the Secure Shell extension of Chrome, but all the connections are refused as long as it is sent from my PC.

However, my PC can connect to the server when they're in the same wifi environment using 192.168.** .**

I'm really confused **why only my PC gets connection refused (only when using the server's public ip address)**.

By the way, the server is an Intel Edison board with yocto linux on it.

Comment: Just to be sure: Your SSH server is on a different physical machine then the machine you are having the problems on?

Comment: Yes, the server is on Intel Edison board ( like Raspberry board).  Since only my personal computer's connection  is refused, I think there maybe some problems with my local environment (just my thought). I might once connect the board with SSH from my computer a long time ago, and then flashed the firmware of the board. Anyway, I can connect to it using 192.168.\*\*.\*\*

Comment: do you have firewall on your laptop?, try disable for while... if it help then add outgoing rule to 22 port

Comment: Also your Windows firewall, as that is a silent killer. If that looks OK, check your event viewer for details, it might be that there is some information in there.

Comment: I disabled the firewall but still can't connect to the server. I didn't find helpful information in event viewer either.